# addEventListener click event is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a project on paper-rock-scissor that has UI. So, I have four buttons, *Start game, rock, paper* and *scissor*. Previously I write the code separately and it works. But right now because I want the result from clicking the button to be an input to another function. So I tried to group all the buttons altogether in my code below. However, it seems like the button doesnt seem to work but there are no errors. I have no idea why? Below are my code :

------------- HTML ---------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project Rock Paper Scissors</title>
        <script src = "javascript.js" defer> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="startgame"> Start game </button>
            <button id="rock"> Rock </button>
            <button id="paper"> Paper </button>
            <button id="scissor"> Scissor </button>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>

</html>
```

------------ Javascript ---------------

```
const button = document.querySelector(".btn-group");
const startGame = document.querySelector('#startgame');
const rock = document.querySelector('#rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('#paper');
const scissor = document.querySelector('#scissor');

 button.addEventListener('click', function(selection) {
        if (selection === startGame) {
            startGame.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissor");
            })
        }  else if (selection === rock) {
             rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let item = "rock";
                return item.toLowerCase();
            })
        }  else if (selection === paper) {
            paper.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let item2 = "paper";
                return item2.toLowerCase();
            })
        } else if (selection === scissor) {
            scissor.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let item3 = "scissor";
                return item3.toLowerCase();
            })
            }            
    })
```

----------- Js code above to be used as argument to function playRound(.... , ....) below ------------

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)  {
        if (playerSelection === "Paper".toLowerCase()  && computerSelection.toLowerCase()  === "Rock".toLowerCase() )  {
            console.log(`Player choose ${playerSelection} and computer plays ${computerSelection} player wins !`);
        } else if (playerSelection  === "Scissor".toLowerCase()  && computerSelection.toLowerCase() === "Paper".toLowerCase() ) {
            console.log(`Player choose ${playerSelection} and computer plays ${computerSelection} player wins !`);
        }  else if (playerSelection  === "Rock".toLowerCase()  && computerSelection.toLowerCase() === "Scissor".toLowerCase() ) {
            console.log(`Player choose ${playerSelection} and computer plays ${computerSelection} player wins !`);
        }  else if (playerSelection  ===  computerSelection.toLowerCase()  ) {
            console.log(`Player choose ${playerSelection} and computer plays ${computerSelection} game is draw !`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Player choose ${playerSelection}, computer plays ${computerSelection}, computer wins !`);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have confused what is passed to an event callback, which is not the element that triggered the event, but rather an [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object with properties describing the event (including the element which triggered it as `event.target`). Your second problem is that even if you handled the event correctly you would simply be adding new listeners on every click, rather than handling the click itself.

Comment: I think it should be `function(ev) { ... }` instead of `function(selection) { ... }` and then when you compare the source of the event you should use `ev.target === startGame` instead of `selection === startGame`. And last but not least I would register all click listeners at once and *never* inside an event listener. If the game is started a second time, all buttons would have multiple event handlers. **not tested**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Answer (score 3):

you have a bug in your code where `selection` is an event object, and not the element which generated the event:

```
 button.addEventListener('click', function(selection) { ...
```

Your `if` statements are comparing `selection` (the event object) to strongly equal the elements that were clicked, which is where it is getting skipped. On the event object `selection` you'll find the `target` property: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

So you might write your if statments this way:

```
if ( selection.target == startgame ) { ....
```

Finally, the event listener is on the outer div and not on each button themselves.

Perhaps an example might help showing one of many ways it is possible to script this:

```js
function computerSelection () {
    return Date.now() % 3;
}

function resetScoreBoard( parent ) {
    console.log('reset ccoreboard');
    scoreboard = document.querySelector('#scoreboard');
    if ( scoreboard ) {
        scoreboard.textContent = ''; // reset the contents
    } else {
        scoreboard = document.createElement('div');
        parent.appendChild( scoreboard );
    }
    scoreboard.id = 'scoreboard';

    scoreboard.player = document.createElement('fieldset');
    scoreboard.player.className = 'score';
    scoreboard.player.style.display = 'inline';
    scoreboard.player.innerHTML = `<legend>Player</legend>`;
    scoreboard.player.score = document.createElement('span');
    scoreboard.player.score.innerHTML = '0';
    scoreboard.player.appendChild(scoreboard.player.score);
    scoreboard.appendChild( scoreboard.player );

    scoreboard.computer = document.createElement('fieldset');
    scoreboard.computer.className = 'score';
    scoreboard.computer.style.display = 'inline';
    scoreboard.computer.innerHTML = `<legend>Computer</legend>`;
    scoreboard.computer.score = document.createElement('span');
    scoreboard.computer.score.innerHTML = '0';
    scoreboard.computer.appendChild(scoreboard.computer.score);
    scoreboard.appendChild( scoreboard.computer );

    scoreboard.result = document.createElement('span');
    scoreboard.appendChild(scoreboard.result);
    return scoreboard;
}


function score ( playerSelect ) {
    let computerSelect = computerSelection();
    switch ( playerSelect ) {
        case 0: switch ( computerSelect ) {
            case 0:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Rock vs. Rock: draw!`;
                return;
            case 1:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Rock vs. Scissors: Player wins!`;
                scoreboard.player.score.innerHTML = parseInt(scoreboard.player.score.innerHTML) + 1;
                return;
            case 2:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Rock vs. Paper: Computer wins!`;
                scoreboard.computer.score.innerHTML = parseInt(scoreboard.computer.score.innerHTML) + 1;
                return;
        }
        case 1: switch ( computerSelect ) {
            case 0:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Paper vs. Rock: Player wins!`;
                scoreboard.player.score.innerHTML = parseInt(scoreboard.player.score.innerHTML) + 1;
                return;
            case 1:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Paper vs. Paper: draw!`;
                return;
            case 2:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Paper vs. Scissors: Computer wins!`;
                scoreboard.computer.score.innerHTML = parseInt(scoreboard.computer.score.innerHTML) + 1;
                return;
        }
        case 2: switch ( computerSelect ) {
            case 0:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Scissors vs. Rock: Computer wins!`;
                scoreboard.computer.score.innerHTML = parseInt(scoreboard.computer.score.innerHTML) + 1;
                return;
            case 1:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Scissors vs. Paper: Player wins!`;
                scoreboard.player.score.innerHTML = parseInt(scoreboard.player.score.innerHTML) + 1;
                return;
            case 2:
                scoreboard.result.innerHTML = `Scissors vs. Scissors: draw!`;
                return;
        }
    }
}

function play ( event ) {
    let selection = event.target.id;
    switch ( selection ) {
        case "startgame":
            scoreboard = resetScoreBoard( event.target.parentElement );
            return alert("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissor");
        case "rock": return score(0);
        case "paper": return score(1);
        case "scissor": return score(2);
        default: console.error(`Unhandled button ${ event.target.id }`);
    }
}

let scoreboard;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-group > button");
buttons.forEach( function( button ) {
    button.addEventListener('click', play );
});
```

You can check out the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ReinsBrain/b3ag5cpy/3)

It might be fun to allow the computer to remember player selections and timestamps to try to intuit the player's choice. Saved to a server and you could compare heuristics across many players to try to make it even more competitive and requiring players to intuit and defy instincts.

Comment: Hey thanks for the guidance. That event.target is something new for me. Now I got all my buttons working by using 'button.addEventListener('click', function(selection) {
        if (selection.target == startGame) {...' and so on. Now my concern is how can I use the result for this button as an argument for my playRound function ?

Comment: @JabriJuhinin - i added an example that you may find helpful. Nothing much else to do on a Sunday morning :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few of issues there:

1. You're waiting until a click occurs anywhere within `.btn-group` before you add click handlers to the buttons themselves. That doesn't make any sense. You would *either* use an overall click handler on `.btn-group` and use event delegation to determine what button was pressed, *or* use event handlers on the individual buttons (probably simpler in this specific case).
2. An event handler receives an **event object**, not an element, so `selection` will never match `startgame` or any of the others. The event object's `target` property refers to the element where the event was targeted, so with your markup that would match one of your buttons (but beware that if you had `<button><strong>xyz</strong></button>`, it would be the `strong` element, not the `button` element, so you'd have to handle that, perhaps with [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)).
3. You're returning `item.toString()` from your inner event handlers, but that doesn't do anything useful. The return value from an [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) event handler is completely ignored.

The simple way to fix #1 and #2 is (in this case) to remove the `.btn-group` handler entirely and just hook up the buttons directly. To fix #3, you have to provide yourself some way of showing that information in the DOM. There are dozens of ways of doing that, so I won't go into specifics here, but you can't just return it and have anything useful happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add events when `.btn-group` is clicked:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".btn-group");
const startGame = document.querySelector('#startgame');
const rock = document.querySelector('#rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('#paper');
const scissor = document.querySelector('#scissor');

function addEvents(){
    startGame.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissor");
    })
     rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let item = "rock";
        return item.toLowerCase();
    })
    paper.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let item2 = "paper";
        return item2.toLowerCase();
    })
    scissor.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let item3 = "scissor";
        return item3.toLowerCase();
    })
}

button.addEventListener('click', addEvents)
```